# CSS Background Naturaly Scaling content

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am moving from a desktop background at 100% and changing to a mobile background once I hit a tablet/mobile size. My problem is as I go down in size, the content starts to exceed the background length.

```
#bg {
background-image: url('images/bg.gif');
background-size: 100%  ;               
background-repeat: no-repeat;    
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}
```

Then going to 992px. This image is 992px width and 1425px height

```
#bg {
background-image: url('images/mobile/mobile-bg.jpg');
background-size: 100% auto; 
}
```

HTML structure

```
<div class="row main-content" > 
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="bg">
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- content here -->
                </div> 

            </div> 
        </div>   
    </div>  
 </div> <!-- row main-content end -->
```

I don't get why it is able to scale and keep the content until it gets smaller (e.g. the mobile size)

What am I missing? I don't want to stretch the image. I want to maintain the right ratio. Do I just need an bg image with even larger height?

Comment: Try wrapping the `main-content` div with a `container` div.

Comment: it has a container around it. I didn't include it in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for background-size of either `cover` or `contain`. MDN has more on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

`Cover` will make the background image as small as possible while maintaining the aspect ratio and `contain` will make sure the background image is as large as possible while maintaining ratio.

If you need to support IE below version 9, you'll need some sort of a polyfill.

```
#bg {
    background-image: url('images/bg.gif');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: cover seems to be an improvement. I end up with space in the right margin of the background.. not sure why..like as if it's not covering 100% of the width

Comment: Do you have an example online? MDN links to an example here: http://whereswalden.com/files/mozilla/background-size/page-cover.html that uses cover and there are no margins, the resolution does get a bit rough though. Check the div you have the image on doesn't have a margin or padding that's causing issue or even the container that holds that div.

Answer (score 1):

I dont quiet exactly get what your your tryin to achieve you may want to look at this
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/

Chances are this is what you want, as it will scale and crop the picture according to device size.

```
 .bg{
    background:url(imgurl/picture.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This personally what I'd use. Most likely using 3 different appropriate sized images in media queries for phone, large tablet, large desktop. Not because the image wouldn't scale, but to save bandwidth for smaller devices.

Comment: Is there a reason why cover then creates space on the right hand side. It sticks to the left side of the screen but doesn't seem to reach 100% width

Comment: yes row by default has margins on left and right. If you remove them it should make the space disappear.

Comment: okay, it's not perfect as cover seems to chop off sides as it gets to the smallest browser width. i guess that's the best it can do with the res